# Ansible giving ssh_exchange_identification ERROR

Tags: ssh, ansible

My Ansible playbook connects to a remote node using a Proxy.

When the Ansible play book runs; it gives the following ERROR while doing the ssh step.

```
[root@vm1-msdp ANSIBLE]# ansible-playbook fend_file.yaml -i env/target -vvvvv

PLAY [LAB1] ******************************************************************* 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
<10.169.99.222> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: msdp
<10.169.99.222> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<10.169.99.222> EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ProxyCommand="nc -x 142.133.134.161:1088 %h %p" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o User=msdp -o ConnectTimeout=10 10.169.99.222 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1473708903.98-28407509853006 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1473708903.98-28407509853006'
fatal: [10.169.99.222] => SSH Error: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
```

But when I run the ssh command myself, I am able to successfully connect.

```
[root@vm1-msdp ANSIBLE]# ssh -C -tt -o ProxyCommand="nc -x 142.133.134.161:1088 %h %p" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 10.169.99.222
root@10.169.99.222's password: 
Last login: Mon Sep 12 12:28:19 2016 from 10.169.102.6
root@IC02 ~ #
```

Do I need to clear any ansible files ?

Comment: Check your ssh permission for the user "msdp" on 10.169.99.222

Answer (score 0):

When you run the SSH command manually, you are specifying the root user. Your Ansible playbook is using your local user of `msdp`. Try setting your `ansible_user` variable in your inventory file. Maybe something like:

`10.169.99.22 ansible_user=root`